# Use short URL when sharing a link in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

The Share feature should use a short permalinks of the questions and answers (e.g. `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226263/95`, not `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226263/use-short-url-when-sharing-a-link`).

Comment: short is beautiful!

Comment: Yup! Would be a better idea .. even they would have to write less code to get just the question id :) Nice idea ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it was working until Feb 10 when I broke it.  Fixed in the next build.

Comment: It's been fixed in version 0.1.30.